# Print list of albums of fotos

Tags: photos.app

## Problem description:

I have imported an old iPhoto library from an old computer running Mac OS X Leopard 10.5 in photos.app running on macOS Catalina (sadly, I cannot state the exact versions of the applications, though). I'm not sure if this has worked correctly. When selecting all events, the status bar says something like "xxx objects in yyy events". Photos.app doesn't know *events* any longer, but during import, for every event encountered it creates one album. When selecting all those albums, photos.app says "xxx images, yyy videos in zzz albums. The thing is, the numbers don't work out.

## My ideas:

I would like to look into that. Is it possible to have iPhoto and photos.app emit a list of events/albums/objects within an {event|album}, perhaps on the command line? With such a list, I could diff them and find missing objects quickly.

Comment: Maybe you could install OS X in a VM and have a play with iPhoto?